# Use .htaccess to force domain for all file paths

Tags: .htaccess, path

I have a website setup on a test server and the web address is along this format:

http://01.23.45.66/~websitename/

The site loads, but all images are calling http://01.23.45.66/images and not http://01.23.45.66/~websitename/images.  Same for javascript files and CSS.

How can I set the .htaccess file to force this second URL segment for file paths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your first rule in Apache config or site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:images|js|css)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /~websitename/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: .htaccess is in the root of the project.  As mentioned above, the CSS, JS etc are all calling http://01.23.45.66/images and not http://01.23.45.66/~websitename/images.

Comment: inside the public_html folder.

Comment: It doesn't load.  As i mentioned above, it needs to be http://01.23.45.66/~sitename/images/abcd.jpg.  In the html the images are called by src="/images/abc123.jpg".  This is a test server environment hence the /~sitename/

Comment: Yes it is working, but your code does not work.  It is still calling images as /images/abc.jpg, rather than /~copeu/images/abc.jpg

Comment: All that is in the htaccess is your code above.  And it does not work.

Comment: **Exact same rule** is working fine on my Apache from `DocumentRoot` .htaccess

Comment: So referencing an image as <img src="/image.png" /> on your index.html calls http://01.23.45.66/~sitename/image.png??  as mine are all calling http://01.23.45.66/image.png which is wrong.

Comment: No, when I visit a `http://localhost/images/image.png` it gets redirected with 301 status to `http://localhost/~sitename/images/image.png`

Comment: If I visit the file, I get a 404.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128301/discussion-between-anubhava-and-matt-price)

Comment: Then it is some problem with your config/setup. As you're not really providing any details about it so it cannot be guessed.